# Does $changedAttributes in afterSave() is the same as $this->getDirtyAttributes()?

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);

    // code for after save
}
```

From the code above, I'm understanding that the variable `$changedAttributes` in the `afterSave()` method are the same with `$this->getDirtyAttributes()`, right?

Answer (score 2):

No. `getDirtyAttributes()` returns state after object was saved, while `$changedAttributes` returns state before save. `$changedAttributes` also contains only attributes which were saved during `save()` or `update()` call, not all changed attributes. So if you have model with two fields: `id` and `name`, and:

1. If you change both fields and call `save()`, then in `afterSave()` `$this->getDirtyAttributes()` will return empty array (since there is no unsaved changes in object) while `$changedAttributes` will contain both attributes with old values (since both attributes were saved).
2. If you change both fields and call `save(true, ['id'])`, then `$this->getDirtyAttributes()` will return array with value of `name` (since this is changed attribute, but not yet saved) and `$changedAttributes` will contain array with value of `id` (since this attribute was updated).

For more insights you can refer to [`BaseActiveRecord::updateInternal()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/9e5c4abdb8d99811b8c4fdc5dc376e22c9f0d662/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L792-L828) implementation.